# Drawing a star in AWT

Tags: java, beginner, graphics, awt

I am new to java and graphics, and I am creating a java program that draws a star. It took me a few hours, but I finally have it drawing a star, but I am wondering if there is a better way to write the "draw" method without having to repeat myself over and over. I am trying to use loops to minimize all this code, but I am having trouble implementing it.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/**
   A Star shape that can be positioned anywhere on the screen.
*/
public class Star
{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double radius;

    private final static double FACTOR = 2.63;
    private final static double ALFA = 18*Math.PI/180;
    private final static double BETA = 54*Math.PI/180;

    private final static double[] X = {0,Math.cos(BETA)/FACTOR, Math.cos(ALFA ),
                                            Math.cos(ALFA )/FACTOR, Math.cos(BETA),0,
                                            -Math.cos(BETA),-Math.cos(ALFA)/FACTOR,
                                            -Math.cos(ALFA ),-Math.cos(BETA)/FACTOR,0};

    private final static double[] Y = {-1,-Math.sin(BETA)/FACTOR, -Math.sin(ALFA ),
                                            Math.sin(ALFA )/FACTOR, Math.sin(BETA),1/FACTOR,
                                            Math.sin(BETA),Math.sin(ALFA )/FACTOR,
                                            -Math.sin(ALFA ),-Math.sin(BETA)/FACTOR,-1};

    private int[] xCoordOfStar; // x coordinates of the vertices of the star as pixel
    private int[] yCoordOfStar; // x coordinates of the vertices of the star as pixel           

     /**
    Calculates the coordinates of a 5 points star 
    @param radius, the length in pixel of each arm of the star from its center 
    @param x the x coordinate of the center of the star
    @param y the y coordinate of the center of the star
    */



    public Star(double radius , double x, double y){

        xCoordOfStar= new int[X.length];
        yCoordOfStar= new int[Y.length];
        int i; 
        for (i=0; i<X.length; i++){
            xCoordOfStar[i] = (int)(radius*X[i]+x);
            yCoordOfStar[i] = (int)(radius*Y[i]+y);
        }   
    }


    public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
    Point2D.Double r1 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[0], yCoordOfStar[0]);
      // The front of the roof
      Point2D.Double r2 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[1],yCoordOfStar[1]);
      // The rear of the roof
      Point2D.Double r3 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[2], yCoordOfStar[2]);
      // The bottom of the rear windshield
      Point2D.Double r4 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[3],yCoordOfStar[3]);
    Point2D.Double r5 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[4], yCoordOfStar[4]);
      // The front of the roof
      Point2D.Double r6
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[5], yCoordOfStar[5]);
      // The rear of the roof
      Point2D.Double r7 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[6], yCoordOfStar[6]);
      // The bottom of the rear windshield
      Point2D.Double r8 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[7], yCoordOfStar[7]);
    Point2D.Double r9
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[8], yCoordOfStar[8]);
      // The front of the roof
      Point2D.Double r10 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[9], yCoordOfStar[9]);
    Point2D.Double r11 
            = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[10],yCoordOfStar[10]);

    Line2D.Double first
            = new Line2D.Double(r1, r2);
        Line2D.Double second
            = new Line2D.Double(r2, r3);
        Line2D.Double third
            = new Line2D.Double(r3, r4);
    Line2D.Double fourth
            = new Line2D.Double(r4, r5);
        Line2D.Double fifth
            = new Line2D.Double(r5, r6);
        Line2D.Double sixth
            = new Line2D.Double(r6, r7);        
    Line2D.Double seventh
            = new Line2D.Double(r7, r8);
         Line2D.Double eigth
            = new Line2D.Double(r8, r9);
    Line2D.Double ninth
            = new Line2D.Double(r9, r10);
    Line2D.Double tenth
        = new Line2D.Double(r10,r11);


      g2.draw(first);
      g2.draw(second);
      g2.draw(third);
      g2.draw(fourth);      
      g2.draw(fifth);      
      g2.draw(sixth); 
      g2.draw(seventh);
      g2.draw(eigth);
      g2.draw(ninth);
      g2.draw(tenth);      


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than having two separate arrays for `x` and `y` coordinates, you should consider an array of `Point`s.

As for your loops question, when creating the points, your loop can look like this:

```
points[i] = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[i], yCoordOfStar[i]);
```

and then your lines (probably in a separate loop):

```
lines[i] = new Line2D.Double(points[i],points[i+1]);
g2.draw(lines[i]);
```

(Note that this works because you have 11 points for 10 lines, and your first and last points match.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need references to all of the points, you are only re-using the last used point, thus the method can be reduced to:

```
public void draw(
        final Graphics2D g2) {
    ////
    Point2D.Double last = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[0], yCoordOfStar[0]);
    for (int i = 0; ++i < xCoordOfStar.length;)
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(last, last = new Point2D.Double(xCoordOfStar[i], yCoordOfStar[i])));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess i figured it out!

I used :

```
g2.drawPolygon(xCoordOfStar, yCoordOfStar, POINTS);
```

it does the job with the least amount of code!

Comment: How does this translate to the given `FACTOR`, `ALFA` and `BETA`?